# "User is Typing" Logics implementation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show a message when a user is typing and hide the message after a timeout period is reached, I am using this logic with `React Native` and `Gifted Chat`.

```
     updateTyping() {
        var TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH= 1000;

        if (this.state.connected) {

            if (!this.state.typing) {
                this.setState({typing : true})
                console.log('typing')   
            }

            var lastTypingTime = (new Date()).getTime();

            setTimeout( () => {

                var typingTimer = (new Date()).getTime();
                var timeDiff = typingTimer - lastTypingTime;

                if (timeDiff >= TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH && this.state.typing) {
                console.log('Stop typing')
                this.setState({typing : false});
                }

            }, TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Socket Cannot connect.")
        }
    }
```

Now the `typing` message keeps hiding and showing (blinking) even when the user is typing.

**Logics**

Now logically the `typing` message should show and if after 1000ms idle, the `typing` message hides.

Is there something I am not doing right from my snippet. Any Ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: if I'm understanding this right, every second that goes by it's going to turn off regardless. You should try to set the timeout to a variable that's defined where it's accessible anywhere (outside the updateTyping function). Set the variable to setTimeout, like `timeoutVar = setTimeout(...` and then in your `if(!this.state.typing)` make an else statement and just do this: `clearTimeout(timeoutVar)` so any time they are typing it should stay. The only time it turns off is if they are not typing. (the timeout will execute).

Comment: Which would get rid of the need for the date stuff (probably the source of your problem). You wouldn't need the date comparison if you just did that.

Comment: Also i dont even understand your date comparison anyways. `timeDiff` will always be greater than `TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH`, since you're waiting AT LEAST that much to execute it. Doesn't make sense to me why you're doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my implementation of doing your code but better (as explained in comment).

```
        if (!this.state.typing) {
            this.setState({typing : true})
            console.log('typing')   
        } else {
            clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
        }

        //var lastTypingTime = (new Date()).getTime();

        timeoutVar = setTimeout( () => {
            //you dont need to do this. either do this and no timeout,
            //or do timeout and not this. It's virtually doing the same thing.
            //
            //var typingTimer = (new Date()).getTime();
            //var timeDiff = typingTimer - lastTypingTime;

            //if (timeDiff >= TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH && this.state.typing) {
            console.log('Stop typing')
            this.setState({typing : false});
            //}

        }, TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH);
```

The only important thing about this is you need to make sure that `timeoutVar` is defined somewhere outside of updateTyping, but accessible. Otherwise this doesn't work. The idea behind it is this: we set a timeout to do something and it's going to fire in the time we tell it to `TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH`, however every time we type something (assuming from your code this function gets hit when they type) we clear the timeout so it doesn't fire. The only time it fires is if we don't clear it, which will be if they stop typing (again, assuming from your code).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not good at react but upto my knowledge. Using timer is really a bad idea until or unless you the property is exact time bounded.
Sol:
Try to display the message using  OnFocus and hide it when it goes away from that text box.